# How to change PGAdmin default owner when creating a schema?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I just installed PGAdmn 4 and PostgreSQL and want my name to be the default owner of schemas, not postgres. How to avoid having to click and select my own name every time I make a schema?

Comment: The "default" owner is the user who creates the schema. So just log in with your database user, not with postgres

Comment: That worked immediately.